# How can you identify which NPCs are "Elite" in The Division?

Tags: the-division

I have a pair of knee pads that provide an 8% bonus "Protection from Elites."

How can I tell which NPCs are "Elite" mobs?

Comment: Keep in mind that according to the April 29th [State of the Game](http://tomclancy-thedivision.ubi.com/game/en-US/news/152-248601-16/state-of-the-game-april-29th-2016), this bonus is still bugged and *increases* the damage you receive from elites!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a [couple](http://thedivision.wiki.fextralife.com/Enemies) [sources](http://www.videogamer.com/features/game_guide/tom_clancys_the_division_guide_item_and_enemy_colour_codes_and_what_they_mean.html#enemy-colours-in-tom-clancy's-the-division), elite enemies are those with yellow/gold HP bars. Named enemies also have yellow HP bars and would presumably also fall into this category.

Comment: I wonder about _Named_. At first I was under impression that they are _Named Elites_, but the wording on some bonuses is `Elites or Named enemies`, which would suggest that _Named_ are not automatically _Elites_.

Comment: @vartec Yeah, it wasn't immediately obvious. Based on my own observations, I think that they do count, but that's very un-scientific and I'm not at all confident. I'd like to see some more definitive information, but can't find any sources either way.